# Error while moving file in Cache Directory in Iphone

Tags: iphone, caching, move

I am facing problem  to move image file in Cache Directory. My requirement is when I am deleting one file for example image3.png then all other files (suppose there is 9 files like image1.png,image2.png,.....image9.png)after that position (image4.png,....,image9.png) will move to their previous position. I want to rename that files like image4.png to image 3.png.
Below is my code

```
NSError *error=nil;

NSString       *imgName            =    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",3];
NSFileManager  *fileManager        =    [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray        *paths              =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory      =    [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *fullPath                =    [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];
[fileManager    removeItemAtPath: fullPath      error:NULL];

for (int i=3; i<=9 ; i++) {

    NSString    *imgName1   =    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i];
    NSString    *getImagePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName1];

    NSString    *imgName2   =    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i+1];
    NSString    *getImagePath2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName2];

    if ([fileManager moveItemAtPath:getImagePath2 toPath:getImagePath1 error:&error] != YES)
        NSLog(@"Unable to move file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    // Show contents of Documents directory
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", 
          [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

}
```

But its showing following error

```
 Unable to move file: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)
```

Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From `NSFileManager` docs on `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`:

> If an item with the same name already exists at dstPath, this method
>   aborts the move attempt and returns an appropriate error

Delete the file you want to overwrite first.